# how to get the likes stay even if how many times you need to refresh it

Tags: javascript, laravel

[image]
[image]

as what you see in the first picture there's a number 3. When when I about to enter or simply refresh it. See the second picture. My question is how to get the number 3 stay steady even if you refresh it.

My View CODE

```
  if(Auth::check()) { 
        echo ' <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:80px" > <a class="vote upvote" data-product_id="'.$products[$product]->product_id.'" href="hehehe"> <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span> </a> '; } echo   '<span class="vote_count"></span>'; if(Auth::check()) { echo    '<a class="vote downvote" data-product_id="'.$products[$product]->product_id.'" href="#"> <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span> </a> </div>'; 
    }
```

Javascript Code

```
$('.vote').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');
    var voteCount = $(this).siblings('.vote_count');
    $(this).siblings('a.vote').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');      
    if( !$(this).hasClass('active')){
        $.get("{{ URL::route('unvote') }}", {product_id: product_id}).done( function(data){
            console.log(data);
            voteCount.text(data[0].vote_count);
        });
    } else {

        if( $(this).hasClass('upvote')){
            $.get("{{ URL::route('upvote') }}", {product_id: product_id}).done(function(data){
                voteCount.text(data[0].vote_count);
            });
        } else {
            $.get("{{ URL::route('downvote') }}", {product_id: product_id}).done( function(data){
                voteCount.text(data[0].vote_count);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You assume people will know how this functions without seeing any source code and no explanation?

Comment: @NewToJS My bad. Please see my edited post...

Answer (score 1):

From the code that you've given it looks like you are not displaying the vote count until the user clicks up or down. Try echoing the current vote value in your view so the vote count is displayed when the page is loaded

**View Code**

```
if(Auth::check()) { 
    echo '<div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:80px" > <a class="vote upvote" data-product_id="'.$products[$product]->product_id.'" href="hehehe"> <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span> </a> '; 
} 
echo '<span class="vote_count">'.$products[$product]->vote_count.'</span>'; 
if(Auth::check()) { 
    echo '<a class="vote downvote" data-product_id="'.$products[$product]->product_id.'" href="#"> <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span> </a> </div>'; 
}
```